# Databases backup with cron

Tags: debian, cron, backup, database

I'm trying to set up a cron job in order to backup my databases daily.
Here's what I wrote in my crontab file :

```
25 18 * * * root mysqldump -u root -p myPassWord --all-databases | gzip > /var/backup/database_`date '+%m-%d-%Y'`.sql.gz
```

As nothing happened at 18:25, I had a look in my `/var/log/syslog` file (the server is under Debian) here's what I found:

```
Jan 24 18:25:01 ns311475 /USR/SBIN/CRON[16252]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/ispconfig/server/server.sh 2>&1 > /dev/null | while read line; do echo `/bin/date` "$line" >> /var/log/ispconfig/cron.log; done)
Jan 24 18:25:01 ns311475 /USR/SBIN/CRON[16253]: (getmail) CMD (/usr/local/bin/run-getmail.sh > /dev/null 2>> /dev/null)
Jan 24 18:25:01 ns311475 dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured, session=<3xFlL2kNAAB/AAAB>
Jan 24 18:25:01 ns311475 dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured, session=<rhRlL2kNvwB/AAAB>
Jan 24 18:25:01 ns311475 postfix/smtpd[16279]: connect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Jan 24 18:25:01 ns311475 postfix/smtpd[16279]: lost connection after CONNECT from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Jan 24 18:25:01 ns311475 postfix/smtpd[16279]: disconnect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
```

I don't understand the first line, I assume the rest is trying to email the issue but I got nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian has a package for you to take care of dumping, compressing and rotating MySQL data. You can install it with the following command:

> $ sudo apt-get install automysqlbackup

After this daily, weekly and monthly dumps will be placed in */var/lib/automysqlbackup*

Comment: ok, thank you hspaans, I think I'll go with your solution which fits well with my needs and will prevent me from making any big mistake.

Comment: Install went ok, but I just can't find where to set up the daily backup hour and minutes. In /etc/default/automysqlbackup only allows to edit day of week...

Comment: The package automysqlbackup installs a script in /etc/cron.daily and all the scripts in that directory are being executed daily by the line with "run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily" in /etc/crontab.

Answer (score 2):

Read the fine manual: `man 5 crontab` : There you will see that "%" has a special meaning for cron.

That is clobbering up your intended command.

apart from this this is a very bad way to start a mySQL-backup:

- Your root-DB-password will appear in the process list viewable for every local user or every user with snmp read access
- You should not start a subshell in a shell for no apparent reason. Use "$(command)" instead.
- gzip will only use one CPU. So that part will slow down your whole backup

You should:

- Place your root-DB-password into a file (.mysql - something I do not remember the exact syntax and name of that file) in the root-folder, only accessible by root. This will enable automatic root-login with the password to mySQL
- Place what you are doing into an own script on /usr/local/sbin (propably also only readable for root and a trusted group)
- Call that script via cron.
- Use the full paths for all commands in that script. Cron might not execute in an environment with all "usual" paths set
- use `pgzip` or if you have the space available, compress after the backup is done

Comment: In addition to that `PATH` may not be set properly. In general it is more desirable to create a script. Otherwise sound answer!

Comment: Thanks for the tips Nils, as you might have seen I'm very new to server administration and Linux, but your suggestions make sense to me.